# change color of special characters in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I've a Unicode HTML page (saved in DB), is there anyway that I can programmatically change color of all "." and ":" characters in text (please pay attention that my HTML content has also inline CSS which may contain "." or ":" characters, but I just want to change color of the mentioned characters in real text.

what are my options? One way can be finding these characters in the text and put them in  tag, so that  can be styled, any other suggestion? (if I'm going to use this method, how can I distinguish between HTML/CSS characters and real characters in the text?) I'm using ASP.NET/C#

Comment: Can include `html` , `css` at Question ?

Comment: If you want only asp.net solutions shouldnt you remove the Javascript tag at the very minimum? Sorry if I am mistaken

Comment: I think a JS/CSS based solution would be much better/easier to implement, I mentioned ASP.NET only to make clear my programming method. Any solution that can solve the problem would be highly welcomed!

Comment: I am not familiar with C# or ASP.NET but I am familiar with PHP. You can try to find an equivalent to this function in PHP; `<?php $charToSearch = ':';
echo str_replace($charToSearch,"<span style='color:red;' class='editorGenerated'>".$charToSearch."</span>",$stringFromDB);`
?>

Answer (score 4):

Try utilizing `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\.|:/g` , returning `i` element with `style` attribute set to specific color

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(/\.|:/g, function(match) {
  return "<i style=color:tomato;font-weight:bold>" + match + "</i>"
})
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    I've a Unicode HTML page (saved in DB), is there anyway that I can programmatically change color of all "." and ":" characters in text (please pay attention that my HTML content has also inline CSS which may contain "." or ":" characters, but I just want
    to change color of the mentioned characters in real text. what are my options? One way can be finding these characters in the text and put them in tag, so that can be styled, any other suggestion? (if I'm going to use this method, how can I distinguish
    between HTML/CSS characters and real characters in the text?) I'm using ASP.NET/C#
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the Simple way to change color of any character in HTML language

"Spacial Character"

Comment: <font color = "Red"> *</font>